# How to find slowest queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, profiling

Using Sql Server 2005 Profiler, what events, columns, and filters do you trace to find your slowest queries and stored procedures?

Slow = greater than N seconds, 10 for sake of argument.

Comment: Define "slow". While a query may be slow, this is only relevant to the number of calls made and whether those are critical or not.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

In SQL 2005 you can use management views to find slow running queries. A good script i found a while ago on [SQL server performance](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/tsql_statement_performance_p1.aspx) will help get you started; it lists data with the slowest performing first.

```
SELECT  creation_time 
        ,last_execution_time
        ,total_physical_reads
        ,total_logical_reads 
        ,total_logical_writes
        , execution_count
        , total_worker_time
        , total_elapsed_time
        , total_elapsed_time / execution_count avg_elapsed_time
        ,SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
         ((CASE statement_end_offset
          WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
          ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END
            - qs.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st
ORDER BY total_elapsed_time / execution_count DESC;
```

Comment: do you know the unit of measure on the times: total_worker_time, total_elapsed_time, and avg_elapsed_time?

Comment: The times are in microseconds; MSDN has a good breakdown on the management view http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx

Comment: Yes, those DMV are great - but they are DYNAMIC, too - as their name implies, e.g. they get flushed each time the server starts up. If your server gets rebooted every night, these might not represent a very reliable sample on any given day. So treat those measurements with care - they're dynamic, and might be based on a fairly small sample...

Comment: How would I add a column to this query to give me the stored procedure name?

Comment: @Hades for procedures you are better starting from sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats

Comment: this gives me `user does not have permissions to execute this action`. which roles should I have to run this query?

Comment: To get time in seconds, divide by 1000000.0, e.g. `(total_worker_time / 1000000.0) AS total_worker_time_s`

Comment: @u07ch is it possible to add database name information, i mean is it possbile to see which query runs slow on which database?

Answer (score 15):

Before I use the profiler, I check the built-in usage reports.  Right click a database, Reports, Standard Reports, then Object Execution Statistics.

It lists the currently cached execution plans, along with the amount of resources and the number of times they've been run.  This generally gives a very good idea about what's keeping the server busy.

Comment: @Andomar, Is ok to run that report on a production server?  I tried running that report on one of my production servers, and it still said "retreiving data" after one minute.  I stopped it to be safe.

Comment: @Bill Paetzke: The report should be safe for production even if it runs quite long.  If you don't trust it, you can check the process list for blocking issues!

Answer (score 3):

The duration column does it for me, but sometimes I look at the reads and writes columns too.

I use the TSQL:StmtCompleted filter to get the raw queries. You may want to add others like stored procedures to that, but the tsql is the 'base' you need to view. As the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173892(SQL.80).aspx) says

> "The execution of a stored procedure
>   can be monitored by the SP:Starting,
>   SP:StmtStarting, SP:StmtCompleted, and
>   SP:Completed event classes and all the
>   TSQL event classes."