# Find out the slow running stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-execution-plan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find slowest queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820219/how-to-find-slowest-queries)

In Sql Server 2008, is there any option to find out which stored procedure running slowly among all (When the no. of stored procedures is very large. Ex: 500)

Comment: SQL Profiler, server-side tracing, inspecting the relevant DMV's ..... just Google for "identify slow running query sql server" and you'll get **tons** of articles showing you how to do it...

Comment: I believe the query execution plan would help too... You can also turn on client statistics once you have some hunches as to the culprit

Comment: @Rikon: Using query execution plan, we can check the stored procedure one by one manually. I am looking for automated approach (may be a query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey Kiran Please refer to this question may be it will answer you

[How to find slowest queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820219/how-to-find-slowest-queries)

Comment: Thats absolutely what I am looking for. Thank you