# How to continuously measure EF performance?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, windows-services

I have a huge application that uses Entity Framework 4. It's WCF on the server (hosted inside Windows service) and WPF on the client.
Some of it's parts are slow, and I wonder if it's due to the fact that database access is slow. 
I would like to continuously measure performance of that code, e.g. log every query's execution time (preferrably *including EF's own stuff like materialization*) somewhere to analyze later. How do I do that? 
**Tools like EFProf** (because even if they can measure time it took db server to execute particular query, how do I run them for a week?) **and Glimpse** (it doesn't support Windows service and WPF) **won't do in my case**. 
I considered making my own SqlConnection subclass, but my version only accepts EntityConnection in ObjectContext ctor, and EntityConnection is marked as sealed. And this option will only allow to measure raw sql queries execution time, not EF's code. 
The only options I see now are: 1) to update to EF 6 and write SqlConnection subclass (this won't measure EF's own code) 2) update to later versions and use something like [EF hooks library](https://github.com/dombrovsky/EntityHooks) 
And of course, it's not in a book (just looked at Mastering Enity Framework) - because *most of us only need to work with a library, not know how quick it is* (sarcasm).

Comment: To look at executed query logs you do not have to write SqlConnection subclass, setting `context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;` is sufficient. Just replace `Console.WriteLine` with your own log action. But as you said, this can only let you measure query execution times, not EF code.

Comment: Why not profile the database instead? If you see queries with high IO or durations then tune those by either tuning the DB objects (like indexes) or finding the EF statement and tuning it.

Comment: @Igor database itself may not be the problem

Comment: @AdilMammadov that would require updating to EF6, I presume

Comment: @chester89, yes, it was introduced by EF6. I think that, by updating to EF6 you can get perfermance benefits as well. Be sure to chek [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx) out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find slowest queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820219/how-to-find-slowest-queries)

Comment: @IvanStarostin not quite - I'm interested in combined EF+sql performance, not just queries

Comment: what about glimpse:  http://getglimpse.com/

Comment: @Sampath Glimpse is not an option either as it doesn't support Windows services, and (I assume) WPF apps. I updated the question

Comment: Hmm..Then it's better if you add those `tags` to you question.

Comment: Mind you, logging isn't for free. It will hit performance even more. You better use SQL Server tools like activity monitor (expensive queries) when users are actually working in the slow parts of the application.

Comment: @GertArnold that would mean I have to coordinate with them, which isn't an easy task given they are *really* busy. logging can be done by hand, which means new records can hit the disk once in, say, 5 or 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

There are all sorts of optimizations being made, both in the linq expression caching and what SQL server chooses to cache, the only way is to measure your performance speed and memory consumption

for your case, I think Microsoft has provided a simple way through "[Measuring Entity Framework Performance using ETW](http://www.dotnetspeak.com/entity-framework/measuring-entity-framework-performance-using-etw/)"

Also, You can get some of this info through SQL profiler, it's just a lot more work.

Comment: you forgot to mention it requires an update to EF 6. nonetheless, it's looks like a good option