# Alert for slow running query on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alert

I would like to create a SQL job that runs a query and if it takes over a set amount of time to send me an email alert.  Any ideas how to do this.  I am running SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Seem like a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577233/sql-alert-when-stored-procedure-executes-for-too-long

Comment: @Paul do you want to trial a specific query or are you trying to find *any* slow running query?

Comment: I want to use it on a specific query

Comment: Seems like it would put more strain on the server - thus reducing the amount of useful work it can do (since you're apparently discarding the results of an expensive to compute query, so long as its fast enough)

Answer (score 2):

To measure the run time of a specific query you could simply capture it within the job itself and then either raise an event to trigger an Agent failure alert or send the email yourself in the t-sql using dbmail:

```
declare @Elapsed int,
        @Start datetime = getdate();

--your query
waitfor delay '00:00:03'
--

select @Elapsed = datediff(ss, @Start, getdate());

raiserror('Query ran for %d sec(s)', 10, 1, @Elapsed) with nowait;
```

Downside of this approach is you have to actually complete the query to measure the runtime.

Comment: That's exactly the upside of using Nagios - you don't have to wait for the query to return!

Comment: Or you could have 2 jobs. One starts the other job has a `waitfor delay '00:00:03'` then checks if the other job is running and if so kills it (optionally) and sends the alert. Wonder if service broker has some sort of timeout too.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) and write a test that will check the running time of a query and if the test fails - send you an email. We used to do the same on my company, now we're using another (expensive) tool called [Event247](http://triggerplus.com/pages/en/products/event-management.php?lang=EN)

Comment: I was looking for something I could do on the SQL server.

Comment: according to the link @sam yi posted above, there's no built-in solution for MySql server. But, if you don't want to use external tools, it shouldn't be difficult to take one of the procedures posted on that link and create a php code that will run on scheduled basis (or just run in an infinite loop and "sleep" for a few minutes in between), which will call that "check"-procedure and will email you if necessary.