# How to configure alert and kill longrunning queries in SQL Profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

is there anyway i can configure alert and kill long running queries using SQL Profiler or someithing in Management Studios ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a stored proc which monitor the sysprocesses in master.. credit goes to [SQL Alert when stored procedure executes for too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577233/sql-alert-when-stored-procedure-executes-for-too-long)

First, you'll need a new UDF, which will translate the job id into the process id for a JOIN:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_SysJobs_GetProcessid(@job_id uniqueidentifier)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (substring(left(@job_id,8),7,2) +
    substring(left(@job_id,8),5,2) +
    substring(left(@job_id,8),3,2) +
    substring(left(@job_id,8),1,2))
END
```

And then the sproc:

```
CREATE PROC sp_check_job_running 
    @job_name char(50),
    @minutes_allowed int, 
    @person_to_notify varchar(50) 

AS 

DECLARE @minutes_running int, 
    @message_text varchar(255)

SELECT @minutes_running = isnull(DATEDIFF(mi, p.last_batch, getdate()), 0)
FROM master..sysprocesses p
JOIN msdb..sysjobs j ON dbo.udf_sysjobs_getprocessid(j.job_id) = substring(p.program_name,32,8)
WHERE j.name = @job_name

IF @minutes_running > @minutes_allowed 
    BEGIN
      SELECT @message_text = ('Job ' + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@job_name,1,LEN(@job_name))) + ' has been running for ' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@minutes_running AS char(5)),1,LEN(CAST(@minutes_running AS char(5)))) + ' minutes, which is over the allowed run time of ' + SUBSTRING(CAST(@minutes_allowed AS char(5)),1,LEN(CAST(@minutes_allowed AS char(5)))) + ' minutes.') 
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = @person_to_notify,
        @body = @message_text,
        @subject = 'Long-Running Job to Check' 
    END
```

Then you can exec the stored proc as

```
EXEC sp_check_job_running 'JobNameGoesHere', 5, 'admin@mycompany.com'
```